# defining sliderInput function in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I added a function `sliderInput` into the following code to define a range for the smooth parameter to read this function

```
after_tilde <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(lower,upper,l=20))")
```

in order to do that I define

```
lower <- input$range[1]
upper <- input$range[2]
```

in `reactive` and `renderPrint` sections But I have an error and I donot know where I made a mistake in ui section or server section. I used 
       `sliderInput("range", "Smooth Parameter range:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(0,1000)))` to defind the range. I have this error **object 'lower' not found**. Any advice?

```
library(shiny)
library(quantreg)
library(quantregGrowth)


ui = tagList(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("body{ background: aliceblue; }"))),
  navbarPage(title="",
             tabPanel("Data Import",
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                                                  tags$hr(),
                                                  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "StringAsFactors", FALSE),
                                                  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                                                               choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
                      ),
                      mainPanel(uiOutput("tb1"))
                      ) ),
             tabPanel("95% Continious Reference Intervals",
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                        uiOutput("model_select"),
                        uiOutput("var1_select"),
                        uiOutput("rest_var_select"),                        
           sliderInput("range", "Smooth Parameter range:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(0,1000))
                                                ),
                        mainPanel( helpText("Selected variables and Fitted values"),
                                   verbatimTextOutput("other_val_show")))),
             tabPanel("Model Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
             tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotOutput("scatterplot"))#, # Plot             
             ,inverse = TRUE,position="static-top",theme ="bootstrap.css"))

server<-function(input,output) { data <- reactive({
  lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
  file1 <- input$file
  if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
  read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

})  

output$table <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  data()
})
output$tb1 <- renderUI({
  tableOutput("table")
})
#output$model_select<-renderUI({
#selectInput("modelselect","Select Algo",choices = c("Reference Interval"="Model")) #Logistic_reg
#})
output$var1_select<-renderUI({
  selectInput("ind_var_select","Select Independent Variable", choices =as.list(names(data())),multiple = FALSE)
})
output$rest_var_select<-renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput("other_var_select","Select Dependent Variable",choices =as.list(names(data()))) #Select other Var
})

output$other_val_show<-renderPrint({
   lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
  input$other_var_select
  input$ind_var_select
  f<-data()
  library(caret)
  library(quantregGrowth)
  dep_vars    <- paste0(input$ind_var_select, collapse = "+")
  after_tilde <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(lower,upper,l=20))")
  dyn_string  <- paste0(input$other_var_select, " ~ ", after_tilde)
  Model<-quantregGrowth::gcrq(as.formula(dyn_string),tau=c(0.025,0.975), data=f)
  temp <- data.frame(Model$fitted)
  growthData_b <- cbind(f, temp)
  print(growthData_b)
})


}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with scoping. You define `lower` and `upper` inside a `reactive` function, but they are not defined outside of it!

You could simply add

```
  lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
```

in your `RenderPrint` statement, so the variables are also defined there.

Also, note that your formula contains the text lower and upper, instead of the actual numbers. You can solve that with:

```
after_tilde <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(",lower,",",upper,",l=20))")
```

I added some `logjs` statements from `shinyjs` so we can see both the new and the old formula.

```
  after_tilde <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(",lower,",",upper,",l=20))")
  old_formula <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(lower,upper,l=20))")
  dyn_string  <- paste0(input$other_var_select, " ~ ", after_tilde)
  logjs(after_tilde)
  logjs(old_formula)
```

[image]

Below is code that solves you error, although it returns new ones for me, but we do not have your data. You may want to get this working without shiny first. Hope this helps!

---

```
library(shiny)
library(quantreg)
library(quantregGrowth)
library(shinyjs)


ui = tagList(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("body{ background: aliceblue; }"))),
  navbarPage(title="",
             tabPanel("Data Import",
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                                                  tags$hr(),
                                                  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "StringAsFactors", FALSE),
                                                  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                                                               choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
                      ),
                      mainPanel(uiOutput("tb1"))
                      ) ),
             tabPanel("95% Continious Reference Intervals",
                      sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                        uiOutput("model_select"),
                        uiOutput("var1_select"),
                        uiOutput("rest_var_select"),                        
                        sliderInput("range", "Smooth Parameter range:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = c(0,1000))
                      ),
                      mainPanel( helpText("Selected variables and Fitted values"),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("other_val_show")))),
             tabPanel("Model Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
             tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotOutput("scatterplot"))#, # Plot             
             ,inverse = TRUE,position="static-top",theme ="bootstrap.css"),
  useShinyjs())

server<-function(input,output) { data <- reactive({
  lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
  file1 <- input$file
  if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
  read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

})  

output$table <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  data()
})
output$tb1 <- renderUI({
  tableOutput("table")
})
#output$model_select<-renderUI({
#selectInput("modelselect","Select Algo",choices = c("Reference Interval"="Model")) #Logistic_reg
#})
output$var1_select<-renderUI({
  selectInput("ind_var_select","Select Independent Variable", choices =as.list(names(data())),multiple = FALSE)
})
output$rest_var_select<-renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput("other_var_select","Select Dependent Variable",choices =as.list(names(data()))) #Select other Var
})

output$other_val_show<-renderPrint({
  lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
  input$other_var_select
  input$ind_var_select
  f<-data()
  library(caret)
  library(quantregGrowth)
  dep_vars    <- paste0(input$ind_var_select, collapse = "+")
  after_tilde <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(",lower,",",upper,",l=20))")
  old_formula <- paste0("ps(", dep_vars, ", lambda = seq(lower,upper,l=20))")
  dyn_string  <- paste0(input$other_var_select, " ~ ", after_tilde)
  logjs(after_tilde)
  logjs(old_formula)
  Model<-quantregGrowth::gcrq(as.formula(dyn_string),tau=c(0.025,0.975), data=f)
  temp <- data.frame(Model$fitted)
  growthData_b <- cbind(f, temp)
  print(growthData_b)
})


}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: ,thanks so much for the suggestion, I run the code with your first suggestion but I got an error "Objekt 'lower' nicht gefunden". I edited the code based on your suggestion. could you please run the code to see that you will get the same error or not?

Comment: @ I defined lower and upper in reactive section and also in renderPrint section. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: I think I should not define lower and upper in reactive function because in this section the data has been defined based on imported variables and the lower and upper are not variables and are just the numbers.  server<-function(input,output) { data <- reactive({
  lower <- input$range[1]
  upper <- input$range[2]
  file1 <- input$file , should I defind a seperate reactive function for lower and upper?

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that it returns some new errors. If you keep encountering issues, I strongly recommend you to strip down your app to the bare minimum, and create a new question on Stack Overflow regarding your errors. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable/48343110#48343110).